# Symfony Assetic bundle 2.3 doesn't work with Sass

Tags: symfony, sass, goto, assetic

I have 2 project on my server with the same configuration(Symfony, MopaBootstrapBundle with Sass). 
One works perfect, but it use elder version of Assetic bundle(2.1). 
And the second(with Assetic bundle v.2.3) breaks the server with this message in **error.log**:

**[error] child died with signal 11**

and css is not compiled.

I have compared two versions of the bundle and found that SassFilter class in the newer version use "**goto**" operator.
I tried to change it on "**break 3**" (this has the same logic in this particular method) and everithing works fine.

I searched throw the project and found 2 goto labels with the same name (one in the SassFilter and the other in the LessFilter), but I think that is not the problem because I don't use LessFilter and thanks to lazy loading it souldn't load.

So I googled the issue and didn't find any notices of this problem. May be I should check my server configuration (I have **apache2**) in order to work properly with "**goto**"?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I've the same problem with less filter, have you solved?